# Why I Can't change the dropdown menu color when hover an item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to change the color when I hover a twitter bootstrap dropdown menu item to blue (#428bca) but I can't. It still get white background. What I'm doing wrong?

```
<div class="form-group">

  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn">

      <div id="filter_search" class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span data-bind="label" id="searchLabel"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span></span> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a class="enabled" id="filter_a">Search by A</a></li>
          <li><a class="enabled" id="filter_b">Search by B</a></li>
          <li><a class="enabled" id="filter_c">Search by C</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Search by D</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Search by E</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#">Search by F</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <input id="search" size="30" placeholder="Search here..." maxlength="50" class="form-control" type="text" />
</div>

<span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="id">Search! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>

</span>
```

In My CSS I'm trying

```
 .input-group .btn-group-primary .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  }

.btn-group-primary .dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.btn-group-primary .dropdown-menu li > a:focus {
  background-color: #428bca !important;
}
```

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/gheleri/mL2btnws/15/

Comment: Where is in your html code element with class "btn-group-primary"?

Comment: Was going to ask this too, but then I realized it really didn't matter - the CSS itself is working, but the background color was being overridden by the background-image CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no CSS expert, but: 
Try setting the background-image property instead of the color:

```
.btn-group-primary .dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
.btn-group-primary .dropdown-menu li > a:focus {
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#428bca),to(#428bca));
}
```

You can clean it up (i.e. remove the gradient, etc.) but you  get the idea.

Comment: Dmitry's post above gave me an idea, and removing .btn-group-primary seemed to fix it: see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mL2btnws/28/

Comment: Yeah, it really works! Thanks very much, you save my day.